# converting numeric dates into words inside dictionary

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, dictionary

```
d = {'A1': ['C',
  '2003-01-01 13:01:00',
  'Lang',
  '2012-06-02 07:00:00',
  '55901',
  '2001-09-05 00:00:00'],
    'A2': ['Eds',
  '2002-02-12 10:07:00',
    '12-3-54']}
```

I have a sample dictionary `d` that contains dates e.g `'2003-01-01 13:01:00'` as seen above. (The `len` of my actually `d` is ~700k containing various such dates.)  I am wondering if there is a way to convert dates back to words. For example, `'2003-01-01 13:01:00'` would become `'January 1st, 2003 at 1:01pm'`.

My desired output is as such

```
d = {'A1': ['C',
  'January 1st, 2003 at 1:01pm',
  'Lang',
  'June 2nd, 2012 at 7:00am',
  '55901',
  'September 5th, 2001'],
    'A2': ['Eds',
  'February 12th, 2002 at 10:07am', 
    '12-3-54']}
```

How would I able to accomplish this output?

Comment: You can create a function that takes a list, parse each item in the list into datetime object and skip if failed, reconstruct those into the date format you want, then return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime 
import json

d = {'A1': ['C',
  '2003-01-01 13:01:00',
  'Lang',
  '2012-06-02 07:00:00',
  '55901',
  '2001-09-05 00:00:00'],
    'A2': ['Eds',
  '2002-02-12 10:07:00',
    '12-3-54']}

suf = lambda n: "%d%s"%(n,{1:"st",2:"nd",3:"rd"}.get(n if n<20 else n%10,"th"))
daydict = dict(zip(range(1,32), [suf(n) for n in range(1,32)]))
#construct the datetime according to  the form of 'January 1st, 2003 at 1:01pm'
for k, v in d.items(): 
    index = 1
    for item in v[1::2]:

        tem = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        x = tem.hour-12 if tem.hour > 12 else tem.hour
        y = 'pm' if tem.hour > 12 else 'am'

        d[k][index] = ' '.join([tem.strftime('%B'), daydict[tem.day] + ',', str(tem.year), str(x)+':'+tem.strftime('%M')+y])
        index += 2
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

Output

```
{
  "A1": [
    "C",
    "January 1st, 2003 1:01pm",
    "Lang",
    "June 2nd, 2012 7:00am",
    "55901",
    "September 5th, 2001 0:00am"
  ],
  "A2": [
    "Eds",
    "February 12th, 2002 10:07am",
    "12-3-54"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Refer to the image below it takes the dict and iterates and prints the format.

Comment: You should always post code instead of image of code. Also, your code only operates on a list, not a dict.

Answer (score 0):

### Update at 2019.09.04

full implement about this question:

```py
import datetime
d = {'A1': ['C',
            '2003-01-01 13:01:00',
            'Lang',
            '2012-06-02 07:00:00',
            '55901',
            '2001-09-05 00:00:00'],
     'A2': ['Eds',
            '2002-02-12 10:07:00',
            '12-3-54']}


def num_2_word(n): return "".join([
    str(n),
    ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'][min(n % 10, 4)] if not 11 <= n <= 13 else "th"])


for key, value in d.items():
    new_value = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(value[1::2]):
        print(idx, item)
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        formated_val = ' '.join([
            date.strftime('%B'),
            num_2_word(date.day)+',',
            str(date.year),
            'at',
            str.lstrip(str.lower(date.strftime('%I:%M%p')), '0')
        ])
        d[key][idx*2+1] = formated_val
print(d)
```

---

### old idea[Deprecated]

maybe like this:

```
d = {'A1': ['C',
            '2003-01-01 13:01:00',
            'Lang',
            '2012-06-02 07:00:00',
            '55901',
            '2001-09-05 00:00:00'],
     'A2': ['Eds',
            '2002-02-12 10:07:00',
            '12-3-54']}
for key, value in d.items():
    new_value = []
    for item in value:
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%B , %Y at %I:%M%p')
            new_value.append(date_str)
        except:
            new_value.append(item)
    d[key] = new_value
print(d)
```

but how to format 1,2.. to 1st, 2nd..., and lower the 'PM', 'AM', i don't know now. i will update answer if i know this later.

Answer (score 0):

I have write this code, using map in order to speed it up. But whether it can speed up or not is not sure. What's more, I donot know how to add st after days.

```py
import datetime, time

d = {'A1': ['C',
  '2003-01-01 13:01:00',
  'Lang',
  '2012-06-02 07:00:00',
  '55901',
  '2001-09-05 00:00:00'],
    'A2': ['Eds',
  '2002-02-12 10:07:00',
    '12-3-54']}

def timeReformat(numTime):
    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(numTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        strTime = date.strftime('%B %d, %Y at %I%p')
    except:
        strTime = None

    return strTime


def processDictItem(e):
    k, v = e
    for i, data in enumerate(v):
        strtime = timeReformat(data)
        if strtime is not None:
            v[i] = strtime
    return (k, v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = dict(map(processDictItem, d.items()))
    print(d)
```

output:

```py
{'A1': ['C', 'January 01, 2003 at 01PM', 'Lang', 'June 02, 2012 at 07AM', '55901', 'September 05, 2001 at 12AM'], 
'A2': ['Eds', 'February 12, 2002 at 10AM', '12-3-54']}
```